# jQuery UI (Draggable) : Element is not placed at my cursor position after dropping

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

I am using jquery ui for drag and drop elements with cloning.

After dropping element, element is getting placed away from my cursor position.

> **PS**: I need to use position for my droppable area container (#rpWebPushPopupContainer) for some reason.
>
> - **If I remove css position (relative / absolute / fixed) property for my container, it is working as expected.**
> - It is not working in case of using css position property.

**How can I overcome above issue without changing the position property for my parent container?**

**https://jsfiddle.net/bfm091vd/**

```js
draggableInputNo = 0;

var buttonElement = '<div class="button">Button</div>'
var textElement = '<div class="text">Text Element</div>'

$(function() {
  $("#rpWebPushPopupContainer").droppable({
    drop: function(event, ui) {
      $element = ui.helper.clone();
      $element.resizable();
      $element.draggable();
      $element.selectable();

      if (ui.draggable.hasClass('draggableInput text')) {
        draggableInputNo++;
        $element.attr("id", 'draggableInput' + draggableInputNo);
        $element.appendTo(this);
        $element.append(textElement);
      }
      else if (ui.draggable.hasClass('draggableInput button')) {
        draggableInputNo++;
        $element.attr("id", 'draggableInput' + draggableInputNo);
        $element.appendTo(this);
        $element.append(buttonElement);
      }
    }
  });

  $(".draggableInput").draggable({
    //containment: '#rpWebPushPopupContainer',
    cursor: 'move',
    helper: draggableInputHelper,
  });

});

function draggableInputHelper(event) {
  return '<div id="draggableInput' + draggableInputNo + '" class="draggableInputHelper resizable" ></div>'
}
```

```css
.draggableInput{width:50px;height:30px;padding:1em;float:left;margin:10px 10px 10px 0;background-color:#93f;border-radius:10px;border:1px solid #93f}
.draggableInputHelper{width:100px;height:30px;padding:.5em;margin:10px 10px 10px 0;background-color:#069;border-radius:10px;border:1px solid #069;color:#fff}
#rpWebPushPopupContainer{position:relative;top:10px;width:500px;height:300px;padding:.5em;margin:10px;float:left;border:1px solid #867979;border-radius:4px;background-color:#ff0}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.min.css" />

<div class="draggableInput text">Text</div>
<div class="draggableInput button">Button</div>

<div id="rpWebPushPopupContainer"></div>
```

Comment: When Draggable moves an item, it applies a `top` and `left` style to the element. When you Drop and append it, that style is being carried over. So the Style is making it appear relative to the parent.

Comment: **@Twisty**, Thanks for the clarification. Is there any other alternative while maintaining position property ?

Comment: Not really. Without any styling it would append to the 0,0 of the parent. So if you want it to land where it's dropped, you may want to use Offset instead of Position. Usually you end up reducing it based on the Top Left of the parent.